# ufw firewall deny outgoing but allow browser

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ufw

I want to configure `ufw` firewall in a way, where I can allow "browser" surfing but deny all another outgoing.

I have denied outgoing using `gufw` but it blocked surfing too, so, I allowed "outgoing" anywhere `http` (80) and `https` (443), but was still not able to surf the internet.

Need help in setting up `deny` outgoing but still allow surfing internet with the browser.

Comment: Do you allow outgoing connection to `DNS`?

Comment: It's home PC. do i need to do that ?

Comment: Yes, you must. You `PC` use `DNS` to resolve logical name aka `www.example.com` to `ip address`. Without `ip address` for destination network traffic will not be router.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is to change the default outgoing policy to deny. By default all outgoing traffic is allowed.

```
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
```

Then you must allow outgoing traffic on both port 80 and 443 with these commands:

```
sudo ufw allow out to any port 80
sudo ufw allow out to any port 443
```

Finally, since web browsing require access to a DNS server you must also allow port 53:

```
sudo ufw allow out to any port 53
```

Then reload the firewall rules:

```
sudo ufw reload
```

Confirm the changes with: `sudo ufw status verbose`

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work , I just follow the exact rules mentioned above and I get the error "There is no Internet connection", so I was not able to write comment. After setting ALLOW to outgoing, I am having access to internet again. I am using "Google Chrome" and "firefox" as my browser.

Comment: Hm okay, it works on my machine that is a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. Have you got an IP address if you run ifconfig? What are the result of "nslookup www.google.com"?

Comment: If you take a look in /var/log/ufw.log, are there any rows that contain "[UFW BLOCK]" together with "DPT=53", "DPT=80" or "DPT=443"? Where DPT is the destination port number.

Comment: Yes, I found there were some BLOCK and I realised, I did mistake, instead of ALLOW OUT, I did ALLOW IN and after fixing typo. It is working super fine. This is amazing. Thanks